# Question over the usage of rint

Tags: c++

```
for(i = 0; i < 181; i++)
    {
       unsigned int index = rint(i/db);
        assert(index >= 0 && index < data.ranges_count);
      this->laser_ranges[i*2][0] = data.ranges[index] * 1e3;
    }
```

what is the meaning of  `rint(i/db)`? I am not sure how rint is used...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rint`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/rint.3.asp) is a function that rounds a floating point number to an integer. It is a non-standard function. If `db` is of an integral type, then `i/db` will truncate to an integer and the code will not work as you have expected. Otherwise the `rint(i/db)` is `i/db` rounded to the nearest integer.

As to ***why*** the rounding is needed here(insteas of truncation) depends heavily on the context of your problem which we have absolutely no idea about.

Comment: `rint` is specified in C99, so it's standard, but not standard C++.

Comment: @larsmans: The question is tagged C++ only. Therefore, it's not standard.

Comment: I still have some qns.. why is it when db is integer, it will not work as expected.. btw i is int and db is double in my code.

Comment: @laksh: suppose `i` is `5` and `db` is `6`. `i/db` is `0` (integer division takes only the whole part) and `rint(0)` is 0. But you'd probably expect that `rint(5/6)` would be `1`.  `rint(5/6.0)` is `1`.

Comment: in the rint manual provided by user814628, it says rint() function returns the integral value (represented as a double precision number) nearest to x. what does the double precision number mean? i am not sure abt it?

Comment: @laksh: C or C++ type `double`? :)

Comment: @laksh: It is. Did I say otherwise?

Comment: huh? i do not understand what you are saying. sorry

Comment: It's a standard function since C++11.

Answer (score 2):

It's a call to function named `rint` with a single argument, which in this case is `i` divided by `db`.

Comment: -1000 Doesn't answer second part "I am not sure how rint is used". It's easy, rint is what you do when you need a place to stay, but don't want to own said place.

Answer (score 0):

`rint` rounds to the nearest integer with some error checking.

What really happens here depends on the type of `i` and `db` of course.